# React: using url param break the test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Am writing a unit test for a component that should use the url param.

The test is always failing with this error:

```
BarcodePage line 14:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

here the test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import BarcodePage from './BarcodePage';

const component = shallow(
  <BarcodePage />
);

describe('<BarcodePage />', () => {
  it('render one header', () => {
    expect(component.find('h1').length).toBe(1);
  });
})
```

The component seems to work fine even though the test is failing but that's will break the build also make me unsure of my implementation. 
The component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class BarcodePage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      } 
      render() {
        return (
            <h1>Barcode view {this.props.params.name}</h1>
        );
      }
    }

    export default BarcodePage;
```

Note: the reason I have a constructor when I don't think it's needed is because I read in the react docs that without the constructor the `this.props` will be undefined.

Comment: I believe it's failing because you dont pass `params` to your component and your getter for `params.name` is failing. Try this in the component `{this.props.params && this.props.params.name}` instead of simple `{this.props.params.name}`

Comment: Now the test complain with  `ReferenceError: props is not defined`

Comment: try to pass params to your component in the test `<Barcode params={{name: 'test'}} />`

Comment: That's not correct since the component no getting any props passed

Comment: but you access them in the component `this.props.params` I mean if you access them it means you need to pass them. Or set default values https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values

Comment: Agree, but the props am accessing is the params which pre-defined not a custom props I pass to the component ..

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure what you mean by `pre-defined not a custom props`

Comment: what @yuyokk described is correct. `this.props.params` is passed down as prop when you wire up the component with router. Which means in order to test this you need to pass params  `<Barcode params={{name: 'test'}} />` (also mentioned by @yuyokk)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work

**Barcode.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class BarcodePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Barcode view {this.props.params.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

BarcodePage.propTypes = {
  params: PropTypes.object
};

BarcodePage.defaultProps = {
  params: {
    name: 'Default Name'
  }
};

export default BarcodePage;
```

**BarcodePage.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import BarcodePage from './BarcodePage';

const component = shallow(
  <BarcodePage />
);

describe('<BarcodePage />', () => {
  it('render one header', () => {
    expect(component.find('h1').length).toBe(1);
  });
})
```